# Keras train_step get epoch number

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I've built my own Keras model class inheriting from keras.Model. However, I have a modified training step, where I manually derive the forward pass and compute two different losses which I sum up such that my total loss is total_loss = loss1 + factor*loss2. I observed that I get better results if I decrease the factor during training. My question would be now, what a good solution for this might be. Can I either access somehow the epoch number in the train_step method such that I can compute the factor from the epoch number or is there any other preferable approach?

thanks a lot :)

EDIT:
If I add a counter to the train_step method, it won't increase during training. But this only happens in non-eager mode. If I enable eager mode it works. Any idea on how I could make it work in non-eager mode?

Comment: Same problem here: i need to grow up a ProGAN like network and I'm using the keras train_step. At the moment I cannot find a proper way to access the epoch number.

Comment: I‘ve solved it in the end via a callback (which has access to the epoch number). The callback can change a variable in the model. Make sure that the variable is a tf.Variable and that it is set to trainable=False

Comment: Thanks, I was looking exactly for this solution and I was studying callbacks.

Comment: Hi, reacting to your EDIT - did you eventually manage to run in in a non-eager mode? I have basically the same problem, managed to run it but non-eagerly it is too slow.

Answer (score 0):

You could be getting better results because you are decreasing the step size as your model approaches a local minima on the loss surface. Notice in the following image how a decreasing step size helps avoid overshooting the minimum.
[image]

A common approach to implement this is to schedule the learning rate for training ahead of time in a list, where your model accesses the current factor based on the epoch number i.e. factors[epoch]*loss2. However, there is nothing stopping you from calculating a factor based directly on the epoch number like factor = numpy.e**(-epoch).

However, your approach of using two losses to create a total loss is not something that I have seen before, there may be some other place in your model where you can directly adjust the learning rate rather than indirectly doing it by adjusting the loss.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The theory behind this stuff is the one of variational autoencoders. https://keras.io/examples/generative/vae/. Even though my model is slightly different, the main idea can be seen there: the total loss is decomposed into total_loss = reconstruction_loss + kl_loss. But the model performs better if the reconstruction_loss is weighted and the weight is decreased with increasing epoch number. This has not that much to do with the learning rate.